# Application linking with excel

Tags: java, android

Is there anyway to allow users to plug in and obtain value from an excel spreadsheet to an app? For windows there's apache POI but for android is there anything similar?

Comment: Apache POI is cross-platform, not windows-only. It's working just fine in linux systems, should work in android as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/).

> Java Excel API is a mature, open source java API enabling developers
>   to read, write, and modifiy Excel spreadsheets dynamically. Now java
>   developers can read Excel spreadsheets, modify them with a convenient
>   and simple API, and write the changes to any output stream (e.g. disk,
>   HTTP, database, or any socket).